# how to integrate login with facebook button in my project

Tags: facebook

I am working on a project in which i need facebook integration.
And i am already tried  to create app id and secret key on facebook.
but it not completed how to do that 
and how will I integrate in my project.

Comment: Here you can find everything you need : https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "facebook integration"? Do you really refer to the "login", or just to display those "like" buttons and stuff?

Comment: Check the official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Facebook PHP SDK and build your script. Here is the script which redirect to the login:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once("lib/src/Facebook/autoload.php");

// 1. init facebook
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'     => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
]);

// 2. Login (session_start must be called before)
$helper      = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if ($_GET['code']){ // 4. IF code existing in the url, it is a redirect (after facebook login)

    try {
      // 5. Get Access Token
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {

        // 6. Logged in!
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        // 7. Now you can redirect to another page and use the
        //    access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        try{
            // YOU CAN DO SOMETHING WITH FACEBOOK API HERE
            $response = $fb->get('{DO_SOMETHING_HERE}', $accessToken);
            $result = $response->getDecodedBody();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        }

    }

} else {

    // 3. redirect to facebook link with permission and callback url    
    $redirect_url = {URL_OF_THIS_PAGE};
    $permissions = ['email','publish_actions','public_profile']; // optional
    $loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_url, $permissions);
    header ("Location: ".$loginUrl);
    exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: i would not suggest the php sdk for a beginner. and you should not tell people that they "need to download the php sdk". they really don´t. he did not even mention his programming language, it could be anything. the question just needs to get closed or improved.